# OR definition of filters when using relations in django filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I have three models with a simple relation as below:

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class PersonSession(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='sessions')

class Billing(models.Model):
    DEBT = 'DE'
    BALANCED = 'BA'
    CREDIT = 'CR'

    session = models.OneToOneField(PersonSession,
                                   blank=False,
                                   null=False,
                                   related_name='billing')
    STATUS = ((BALANCED, 'Balanced'),
              (DEBT, 'Debt'),
              (CREDIT, 'Credit'))

    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                              choices=STATUS,
                              blank=False,
                              default=BALANCED
                              )
```

## views.py

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_time = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(name='sessions__start_time',
                                 distinct=True)
    billing_status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(name='sessions__billing__status',
                        choices=Billing.STATUS,
                        distinct=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

class PersonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend)
    filter_class = PersonFilter
```

I want to get billings from person endpoint which have `DE` status in billing and are between a period of time:

```
api/persons?start_time_0=2018-03-20&start_time_1=2018-03-23&billing_status=DE
```

But the result is not what I were looking for, this returns all persons has a session in that period and has a billing with the `DE` status, whether that billing is on the period or not.

In other words, it seems use `or` operation between two filter fields, I think [this post](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18437) is related to this issue but currently I could not find a way to get the result I want. I am using djang 1.10.3.

### Edit

I try to write an [example](https://github.com/mohiz/test_django_filter.git) to show what I need and what I get from django filter. If I get persons using below query in the example, I got just two person:

```
select * 
from 
test_filter_person join test_filter_personsession on test_filter_person.id=test_filter_personsession.person_id join test_filter_billing on test_filter_personsession.id=test_filter_billing.session_id 
where
start_time > '2000-02-01' and start_time < '2000-03-01' and status='DE';
```

Which gets me just person 1 and 2. But if I get somethings expected similar from url I would get all of persons, the similar url (at least one which I expected to be the same) is as below:

```
http://address/persons?start_time_0=2000-02-01&start_time_1=2000-03-01&billing_status=DE
```

### Edit2

This is the data that my queries in the example are upon and using them you can see what must returns in queries that I mentioned above:

```
 id | first_name | last_name | id |        start_time         |         end_time          | person_id | id | status | session_id 
----+------------+-----------+----+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+----+--------+------------
  0 | person     | 0         |  0 | 2000-01-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-01-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         0 |  0 | DE     |          0
  0 | person     | 0         |  1 | 2000-02-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-02-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         0 |  1 | BA     |          1
  0 | person     | 0         |  2 | 2000-03-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-03-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         0 |  2 | DE     |          2
  1 | person     | 1         |  3 | 2000-01-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-01-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         1 |  3 | BA     |          3
  1 | person     | 1         |  4 | 2000-02-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-02-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         1 |  4 | DE     |          4
  1 | person     | 1         |  5 | 2000-03-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-03-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         1 |  5 | DE     |          5
  2 | person     | 2         |  6 | 2000-01-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-01-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         2 |  6 | DE     |          6
  2 | person     | 2         |  7 | 2000-02-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-02-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         2 |  7 | DE     |          7
  2 | person     | 2         |  8 | 2000-03-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-03-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         2 |  8 | BA     |          8
```

### Edit3

I try using `prefetch_related` to join tables and get results as I expected because I thought that extra join causes this problem but this did not work and I still get the same result and this had not any effects.

### Edit4

This [issue](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/883) has the same problem.

Comment: Colocate your filter in a filters.py file, not in views.py. Look if django-filters is in your INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

Comment: How is `Person` related to `PersonSession` or `Billing` models? The above code looks incomplete. What I could make up from the given information is that your'e are associating `PersonSession` with both `Billing` (billing has the `session` attribute) and `Person` (assuming `branch_sessions` reverse mapping as used in the filter). Try filtering using the billings that the person has. 
Something like this should work - `start_time = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(name='billings__sessions__start_time',distinct=True)` assuming `Person` has an attribute `billing`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the problems in models I have forgotten some fields in model. `session` has a foreign key to `person` and `billing` has one to one relation with `session`. Using these assumption I think my filter has no problem and must work as I expected but it does not.

Comment: @GeancarloMurillo I could not understand why changing the file and location where filter implementation has could affect the results of filter? As I explained I get some results from my filter but it is not as what I expect.

Comment: Is an advice for a better organization for your code and good practice skills recommended from Django docs. Your filters in `filters.py`, your signals in `signals.py`, views in `views.py` and so on. Sorry if it doesn't fix your problem. Can you give some example for what are you getting and what you except?

Comment: Please look at my edit note. I am sorry for being late but I tried to write a complete example to show what I needed and what I get, If it is too long for read I could just give you tables and their contents that generate that results.

Answer (score 1):

#### I don't have a solution yet; but I thought a concise summary of the problem will set more and better minds than mine at work!

From what I understand; your core issue is a result of two pre-conditions:

1. The fact that you have two discrete filters defined on a related model; resulting in filter spanning-multi-valued-relationships
2. The way `FilterSet` implements filtering

### **Let us look at these in more detail:**

#### filter spanning-multi-valued-relationships

This is a great resource to understand issue pre-condition #1 better:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Essentially, the `start_time` filter adds a `.filter(sessions__start_time=value)` to your Queryset, and the `billing_status` filter adds a `.filter(sessions_billing_status=value)` to the filter. This results in the "spanning-multi-valued-relationships" issue described above, meaning it will do an `OR` between these filters instead of an `AND` as you require it to.

This got me thinking, why don't we see the same issue in the `start_time` filter; but the trick here is that it is defined as a `DateFromToRangeFilter`; it internally uses a single filter query with the `__range=` construct. If instead it did `sessions__start_time__gt=` and `sessions__start_time__lt=`, we would have the same issue here.

#### The way `FilterSet` implements filtering

> Talk is cheap; show me the code

```
@property
def qs(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_qs'):
        if not self.is_bound:
            self._qs = self.queryset.all()
            return self._qs

        if not self.form.is_valid():
            if self.strict == STRICTNESS.RAISE_VALIDATION_ERROR:
                raise forms.ValidationError(self.form.errors)
            elif self.strict == STRICTNESS.RETURN_NO_RESULTS:
                self._qs = self.queryset.none()
                return self._qs
            # else STRICTNESS.IGNORE...  ignoring

        # start with all the results and filter from there
        qs = self.queryset.all()
        for name, filter_ in six.iteritems(self.filters):
            value = self.form.cleaned_data.get(name)

            if value is not None:  # valid & clean data
                qs = filter_.filter(qs, value)

        self._qs = qs

    return self._qs
```

As you can see, the `qs` property is resolved by iterating over a list of `Filter` objects, passing the initial qs through each of them successively and returning the result. See `qs = filter_.filter(qs, value)`

Each `Filter` object here defines a specific `def filter` operation, that basically takes teh Queryset and then adds a successive `.filter` to it.

Here's an example from the `BaseFilter` class

```
   def filter(self, qs, value):
        if isinstance(value, Lookup):
            lookup = six.text_type(value.lookup_type)
            value = value.value
        else:
            lookup = self.lookup_expr
        if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            return qs
        if self.distinct:
            qs = qs.distinct()
        qs = self.get_method(qs)(**{'%s__%s' % (self.name, lookup): value})
        return qs
```

The line of code that matters is: `qs = self.get_method(qs)(**{'%s__%s' % (self.name, lookup): value})`

So the two pre-conditions create the perfect storm for this issue.

Comment: I got confused because my requirement seems a logical one but it seems that no one had not such a problem in django filter, This gets me thinking that may be the definition of my models or adjusting filters like this is a bad and rare behavior in django modeling. Do you think that the problem could define completely different?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
class FooFilterSet(FilterSet):

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        """
        Overrides the basic methtod, so that instead of iterating over tthe queryset with multiple `.filter()`
        calls, one for each filter, it accumulates the lookup expressions and applies them all in a single
        `.filter()` call  - to filter with an explicit "AND" in many to many relationships.
        """
        filter_kwargs = {}
        for name, value in self.form.cleaned_data.items():
            if value not in EMPTY_VALUES:
                lookup = '%s__%s' % (self.filters[name].field_name, self.filters[name].lookup_expr)
                filter_kwargs.update({lookup:value})

        queryset = queryset.filter(**filter_kwargs)
        assert isinstance(queryset, models.QuerySet), \
            "Expected '%s.%s' to return a QuerySet, but got a %s instead." \
            % (type(self).__name__, name, type(queryset).__name__)
        return queryset
```

Overriding the `filter_queryset` method so that it accumulates the expressions and applies them in a single `.filter()` call