# Django diffrenet results from AND operation and sequential filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filters

If I have models like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class PersonSession(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='sessions')

class Billing(models.Model):
    DEBT = 'DE'
    BALANCED = 'BA'
    CREDIT = 'CR'

    session = models.OneToOneField(PersonSession,
                                   blank=False,
                                   null=False,
                                   related_name='billing')
    STATUS = ((BALANCED, 'Balanced'),
              (DEBT, 'Debt'),
              (CREDIT, 'Credit'))

    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                              choices=STATUS,
                              blank=False,
                              default=BALANCED
                              )
```

The two below query generates different results:

```
Person.objects.filter(Q(sessions__start_time__gte='2000-02-01') & \
                      Q(sessions__start_time__lte='2000-03-01') & \
                      Q(sessions__billing__status=Billing.DEBT))
OR
Person.objects.filter(Q(sessions__start_time__gte='2000-02-01') & \
                      Q(sessions__start_time__lte='2000-03-01')).filter(
                      Q(sessions__billing__status=Billing.DEBT))
```

The first one generates two person 1,2 and the second one generates all three persons that I have, the data is as below:

```
id | first_name | last_name | id |        start_time         |         end_time          | person_id | id | status | session_id 
---+------------+-----------+----+---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------+----+--------+------------
0 | person     | 0         |  0 | 2000-01-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-01-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         0 |  0 | DE     |          0
0 | person     | 0         |  1 | 2000-02-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-02-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         0 |  1 | BA     |          1
0 | person     | 0         |  2 | 2000-03-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-03-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         0 |  2 | DE     |          2
1 | person     | 1         |  3 | 2000-01-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-01-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         1 |  3 | BA     |          3
1 | person     | 1         |  4 | 2000-02-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-02-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         1 |  4 | DE     |          4
1 | person     | 1         |  5 | 2000-03-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-03-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         1 |  5 | DE     |          5
2 | person     | 2         |  6 | 2000-01-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-01-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         2 |  6 | DE     |          6
2 | person     | 2         |  7 | 2000-02-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-02-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         2 |  7 | DE     |          7
2 | person     | 2         |  8 | 2000-03-01 16:32:00+03:30 | 2000-03-01 17:32:00+03:30 |         2 |  8 | BA     |          8
```

I wrote an [example](https://github.com/mohiz/test_django_filter.git) that creates class and data for them to show the difference.

Please explain what is difference between these two queries and as a side question if in django-filter package I want to define some fields to work as a first filter how could I do this?

Comment: Based on the example data, is it possible to see the result of executing the first query and the result of executing the second query? I know you have a github project to do that, but it would be helpful if you could post the results of the two queries here.

Comment: The first query result: `<QuerySet [{'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'1', u'id': 1}, {'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'2', u'id': 2}]>
`and the second one: `<QuerySet [{'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'0', u'id': 0}, {'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'0', u'id': 0}, {'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'1', u'id': 1}, {'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'1', u'id': 1}, {'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'2', u'id': 2}, {'first_name': u'person', 'last_name': u'2', u'id': 2}]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries generated by the filters are different as follows:

```
>>> print Person.objects.filter(Q(sessions__start_time__gte='2000-02-01') & \
...                       Q(sessions__start_time__lte='2000-03-01')).filter(
...                       Q(sessions__billing__status=Billing.DEBT)).query
SELECT "test_filter_person"."id", "test_filter_person"."first_name", "test_filter_person"."last_name" FROM "test_filter_person" INNER JOIN "test_filter_personsession" ON ("test_filter_person"."id" = "test_filter_personsession"."person_id") INNER JOIN "test_filter_personsession" T3 ON ("test_filter_person"."id" = T3."person_id") INNER JOIN "test_filter_billing" ON (T3."id" = "test_filter_billing"."session_id") WHERE ("test_filter_personsession"."start_time" >= 2000-02-01 00:00:00+00:00 AND "test_filter_personsession"."start_time" <= 2000-03-01 00:00:00+00:00 AND "test_filter_billing"."status" = DE)
>>> print Person.objects.filter(Q(sessions__start_time__gte='2000-02-01') & \
...                       Q(sessions__start_time__lte='2000-03-01') & \
...                       Q(sessions__billing__status=Billing.DEBT)).query
SELECT "test_filter_person"."id", "test_filter_person"."first_name", "test_filter_person"."last_name" FROM "test_filter_person" INNER JOIN "test_filter_personsession" ON ("test_filter_person"."id" = "test_filter_personsession"."person_id") INNER JOIN "test_filter_billing" ON ("test_filter_personsession"."id" = "test_filter_billing"."session_id") WHERE ("test_filter_personsession"."start_time" >= 2000-02-01 00:00:00+00:00 AND "test_filter_personsession"."start_time" <= 2000-03-01 00:00:00+00:00 AND "test_filter_billing"."status" = DE)
```

Let's call them Q1 and Q2 respectively.

As you can see, Q1 does the join between `Person`, `PersonSession`, and `Billing` once, and all the conditions are applied together in the `WHERE` clause.

However, in Q2, since you terminate the first filter with the first two checks, this results in a first query join between `Person` and `PersonSession` first (for `Person.objects.filter(Q(sessions__start_time__gte='2000-02-01') & Q(sessions__start_time__lte='2000-03-01'))`, the result this first join is again joined with `PersonSession` and `Billing` in order to execute the second part of the filter query `.filter(Q(sessions__billing__status=Billing.DEBT))`.

You can read more here: [difference between filter with multiple arguments and chain filter in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542874/difference-between-filter-with-multiple-arguments-and-chain-filter-in-django)

Also want to draw your attention to the last line of the post:

> One table: But if the query doesn't involve joined tables like the example from Yuji and DTing. The result is same.

Comment: May be this seems an XY problem but I had [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50001616/2335245) which basically was about django-filter and for finding solution for that problem I notice the difference between these two queries. As the end of this question stated, do you think it is possible to do the first query in django-filter because the first one usually is the one anyone expected.

Comment: I'll try to answer that question on the other thread. If the response here is satisfactory; please close this thread.